# Array by reference

Tags: c

I have an array with a set size of 64 being passed by reference to a function. I'm getting the warning

> warning C4047: 'function' : 'int * ' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (*)[64]'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void hex_to_binary(char* hex, int* arr)
{
    int decimal = strtol(hex,NULL,16);
    int remainder=0;
    int pos = 63; 
    while(decimal!=0)
    {
        remainder=decimal%2;
        decimal/=2;
        arr[pos]=remainder;
        pos--;
    }
}
void print_64bin(int* bin)
{
    int pos;
    for(pos=0; pos<64;++pos)
    {
        printf("%d",bin[pos]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int bin[64]={0};
    int q;
    char hex[20];
    printf("Enter hex\n");
    scanf("%s",&hex);
    hex_to_binary(&hex,&bin);
    printf("Answer\n");
    print_64bin(&bin);
}
```

Can anyone explain why I get this or give a solution?

Comment: Is there a separate prototype for hex_to_arr?

Comment: No there are no prototypes in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the functions correctly.

The way you're calling them now, you're passing the address of an array, but your functions expect a pointer to an `int`.

Pass the arrays to your functions without the address-of operator `&`.  The array will decay to a pointer to the first element.

```
hex_to_binary(hex,bin);
...
print_64bin(bin);
```

Answer (score 2):

`int[64] a;` is not a valid C declaration. It looks like your compiler is pulling some extension tricks on you. You need:

`int a[64];`

Comment: That was my mistake while putting this here, its like that in the code

Comment: In that case the code you've shown is fine. The problem is somewhere else or you've copied it incorrectly.

Comment: The code works I'm just wondering why the compiler thinks its wrong

Comment: It shouldn't (given the examples you have here). Include all your code or we can't help you.

Comment: That's not complete. There's no `main`, for example. Show your *whole* program, including headers.

Comment: That's the only part of the code that actually does anything

Comment: Clearly the problem is not with this part of the code. Show it *all* or we can't help you.

Comment: Ok, the complete code is added. I really don't get how it makes it any different

Comment: Surprise surprise, it is different. Your accepted answer explains why.

Answer (score 1):

Indirection refers to accessing a variable through a pointer. Just as a pointer can refer, or point, to a variable (one level of indirection), a pointer can also point to another pointer that, in turn, points to a variable (two levels of indirection). Because two pointers that have different levels of indirection possibly refer to two different things (one could be pointing to a variable, while the other could be pointing to another pointer), the compiler issues warning C4047 whenever you include such pointers in an expression.

For example, the following code generates this warning but is compiled without change:

```
void main() {
    char **p;// two levels of indirection
    char *q; // one level of indirection
    p = q;   // warning C4047
}
```

Reference - [c4047 warning 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231891(v=vs.60).aspx)

[c4047 warning 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t92260h.aspx)